# d3 xAxis tick margins

Tags: d3.js

x-Axis is generated from the following code:

```
xAxis = d3Axis
      .axisBottom(x)
      .scale(x)
      .tickValues(ticks_X)
      .tickFormat(function (d, i) {
        return tickLabels_X[i];
      });
```

The output is as follows:
[image]

How can just tick first, margin to the right?

Without touching a `tickValues`

Comment: you could change first tick's text anchor attribute to 'start'

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I am trying to solve the problem with D3
Otherwise, yes, I agree with you

Comment: and how what I said isn't D3 solution? `The elements created by the axis are considered part of its public API.` https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#api-reference

Comment: axis.select('.tick').select('text').attr('text-anchor', 'start')